# Weather Rest service

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest

Does anyone know REST service for weather casting which will be available also outside of usa? the only one I found is the national weather service but it works only inside USA.

Thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Google's API out - it's not published, and not REST, but pretty awesome

http://blog.programmableweb.com/2010/02/08/googles-secret-weather-api/

Comment: I am trying to do it via Android application, any idea for any samples how to use it? btw: I need to retrive the weather by latitude/longtitude. can I do it with this one?

Comment: Is it should be parsed as JSON or any other patterns?

Comment: Being XML response, I think it should simply be parsed as XML

Answer (score 4):

http://api.yr.no/weatherapi/documentation is delivered by the Norwegian Meteorological Institute. The most interesting part could be [LocationForecast](http://api.yr.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.8/documentation), depending on your needs, of course.

Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363052/best-weather-apis-free-for-commercial-use

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is out of date, Google API is no more available.

I would recommend Metwit [weather API](http://metwit.com/developers). It's an easy to use fully REST API and it's free to use for many reasonable uses.

(Full disclosure: I am a founder of Metwit. Feel free to ask me for further details)

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch listed on [Programmable Web](http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory/1?apicat=Weather). [Yahoo's](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/) looks promising.